# About the center of phase and the geometric center of an antenna

Tags: electromagnetism, antennas

Suppose we have two antennas $A$ and $B$ in a near-field configuration. Let $P_A,P_B$ centers of phase and $G_A,G_B$ the geometric centers of $A,B$ respectively. $A$ emits a signal which is captured by $B$.

If $A$ emits a signal over time with a maximum at $t_0=0$, at which time $t$ can we expect $B$ to receive that maximum ?

I believe this is somewhat related to the center of phase and/or geometric center of those antennas but I am not sure. 
My first assumption was that the time is $d(P_A,P_B)/c$, where $d(\cdot,\cdot)$ represents the euclidean distance between the two points and $c$ the speed of light. But since the center of phase may be in front of the antenna, it seems weird to think that the antenna will receive the maximum before it physically reaches it. Then may be it is $d(P_A,G_B)/c$ ?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Interesting question and I have simple answer. Nevertheless, if the antennas are in the near field of each other then you do have direct reactive coupling between them, so maybe a lumped element model is more appropriate. Think of it this way, attach a long transmission line to both, so you have well-defined single mode entry and exit modes and points. The antennas represent a mostly reactive coupling between the lines.

Comment: [...]The reactive coupling has an associated group delay that is in addition to any delay that the lines may have, and I do not see any clear relationship between the antennas and that delay because their actual geometric separation determines the reactive coupling not just the geometry of the individual antennas.

Comment: And what if I add the assumption that they are far enough so coupling is negligible ? Thank you for your comment by the way. Finally, do you know, by chance, some reference on this problem ? @hyportnex

Comment: If they are in the far field then I think the phase center can be considered as being the point of emission/reception of the antenna but I do not have any specific reference. In radar where delay does matter it is measured and the *whole system* is fully calibrated by some reference reflector of known distance; note *whole system* not each RF part separately.

Comment: I see. Well actually I am in near field so I need to be as much precise as i can about those point of reception/emission. I have called them  "characteristic time point" at the moment since I cannot find anything about this on litterature.  Thank you again. @hyportnex